# Missing "key" prop for element in array after creating app with create-react-app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint, create-react-app

I'm currently creating a new React application with create-react-app. After that I install eslint that extends plugin:react/recommended and google. 2 weeks ago I did the same and I had no problems but since 2 days I now get a "Missing "key" prop for element in array" error in my index.tsx and App.tsx files for each html line.

##### index.tsx

```
import './index.css';
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';

ReactDOM.render(
    <React.StrictMode>
      <App /> <!-- Here I get a missing key prop error -->
    </React.StrictMode>,
    document.getElementById('root'),
);
```

##### App.tsx

```
import './App.css';
import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
        <p>
          Edit <code>src/App.tsx</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
        <a
          className="App-link"
          href="https://reactjs.org"
          target="_blank"
          rel="noopener noreferrer"
        >
          Learn React
        </a>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

In the App.tsx I get the missing key prop error on all lines inside the `<div className="App"></div>`

I have no idea why I'm getting this error but removing the `plugin:react/recommended` from .eslintrc.yml removes the errors. Probably because the react/jsx-key rule is applied in that ruleset.

I'm also tried removing the `eslintConfig` block frmo package.json

#### Extra info

##### Version

- Node: 16.14.0
- Npm: 8.5.2

##### package.json

```
{
...
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.2",
    "@testing-library/react": "^12.1.3",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "@types/jest": "^27.4.1",
    "@types/node": "^16.11.26",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.39",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.11",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.0",
    "typescript": "^4.5.5",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.12.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.12.1",
    "eslint": "^8.9.0",
    "eslint-config-google": "^0.14.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.29.0"
  }
}
```

##### .eslintrc.yml

```
env:
  browser: true
  es2021: true
extends:
  - plugin:react/recommended
  - google
parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser'
parserOptions:
  ecmaFeatures:
    jsx: true
  ecmaVersion: latest
  sourceType: module
plugins:
  - react
  - '@typescript-eslint'
rules: {
  require-jsdoc: 0
}
```

Any idea what is happing here and how I can solve this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UPDATE: The issue has been fixed in [v7.29.1](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/releases/tag/v7.29.1).

---

This is an error coming from the rule `react/jsx-key` of the plugin `eslint-plugin-react` in its new release (7.29.0).

It has been reported [here](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/issues/3215).

You could downgrade your version of `eslint-plugin-react` to 7.28.0 until the issue is fixed.